# koajs: how to wait for client to receive file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa2

I want to return a generated file with koa (2) and after the client finished receiving the file, the file should be deleted.

```js
// this function is called by Koa
async myMethod (ctx) {
  const file = await something()// generate a file

  ctx.attachment(path.basename(file))
  ctx.body = fs.createReadStream(file)

  // how can I await here for the client to fully receive file?

  await fs.promises.unlink(file)
}
```

I could do this:

```js
ctx.body.on('end', async () => { 
  console.log('client finished receiving') 
  await fs.promises.unlink(file)
})
```

but I would rather put the delete logic in a separate middleware,
and therefore I have to wait for the file to be fully sent before returning from the function

Comment: Maybe something like `await new Promise(resolve => { ctx.body.on('end', resolve) })`?

Comment: @ChrisG I have already tried that, but somehow the promise never resolves this way and hangs forever. Only when I also register an eventlistener for 'data' in the promise it resolves, but then the file-data does not go into ctx.body.